# No audio devices found on Lenovo G500 running 23.04

Tags: sound, lenovo

folks.

I am having audio issues with my Lenovo G500 running Ubuntu 23.04. Audio output works fine, but when I go to sound settings, no input devices are displayed (no input devices found).

Is there any info you need to help me troubleshoot this issue?

I’ve done numerous Google searches to no avail. None of the “fixes” worked for me. Has anyone had any luck?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found this fix on another board. Add the following line to your alsa-base.conf file.

options snd_hda_intel index=1,0

Both input and output now work!